# translate() on side menu object still take up space

Tags: css, translate-animation

I don't know if I am doing anything wrong, but I have a side menu with some icons. When you click one of the icons, it expands about `350px` to the right, and a text is shown that explains this icon.
For that I use some javascript that adds/removes a CSS class if clicked, and then the `transform: translateX()` function is performed, and the icon/bar expands or subtracts (see image). Pretty straightforward imo.

I have recently done it by adding having negative margin, and then change that to 0 when the CSS class is added - which worked. But it seems like the consensus is that you shouldn't `translate` margins (due to performance). Therefore I tried the `translateX()` function, which seemed to work, however, I just figured out that the space it is supposed to occupy when clicked (i.e. the expanded bar (see image)) is somehow taking up the space anyways. So if I were to click somewhere where the bar is supposed to expand to (when closed of course), like a button, I can't because it occupies the space even though it's not expanded.

So is that a property of the `translate` function, or can I fix it somehow ?

EDIT (see this example):
https://jsfiddle.net/1t5Lrgax/

Here you see the side bar, and as you can see, the green button can be clicked just at the top, but not most of its body, which is covered by the side bar WHEN it is unfolded.

[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant code to this post. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it would be a question about whether `translateX()` did this or not, but I have now updated my answer with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your provided example looks fine with no space. Maybe the parent menu has a `margin` or `padding`

Comment: It doesn't look fine to me. If the side menu buttons are closed, can you really push the green button all over ? (okay, I don't know if your resolution makes it so the green button isn't covered by the side button when clicked?). If not, maybe change the `margin-top` of the button, so that it does overlap with the side menu when expanded.